# Automatically update field from weak entity on PostGIS/QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am having a DB centered around objects and a series of tables informing on different attributes for this object. On of these table/attribute is the diameter. It occurs the diameter is strongly linked with the material, i.e. there isn't any diameter having two different material. So the table with the diameter is linked with a weak entity (cardinality 1,1) containing the material datas.

In QGIS, I would like that when I select the diameter of an object I created (or that I am updating), it automatically fill the field relative to the material of the object. How can I do that ? Better even : I would like that the material field in the attribute table to not be editable, and so just be related to the diameter field.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured something out.

In postgresql I simply created a trigger which automatically update the "material" field. The only little problem is that it doesn't display 'on the fly' before saving and refreshing the layer.

Comment: I don't think it would even be possible to display the value before saving and refreshing the layer. It has to commit any changes and that happens when you save the layer.